# 128x128 png with crisp text

Tags: gimp, logo, icon

I am trying to create some buttons for a website I am building. There will be a number of buttons, they are circles that have one or two words written in them. Each button is 128x128 pixels. I am trying to do it on Gimp but the text on the image never looks as crisp as normal text.

I have seen images as small or even smaller than this with very clear and crisp text. Is there a way to do this using gimp or another free tool?

**Update:**
This image shows my textbox setting.

[image]

Comment: Gimp can produce perfectly crisp text as long as you don't scale it afterwards. Maybe what you need is vector graphics (use Inkscape instead of Gimp).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sharpen text in GIMP?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8440/how-to-sharpen-text-in-gimp)

Comment: What is the button text font and font size, what are your settings for the text tool, ...?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher I updated my question with an image that shows my text settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Normal text" is not normal text. It has a subpixel aliasing that makes it crisper than any normal aliasing gimp or photoshop can make on a normal raster image.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering

You can try to use a svg image (made in inkscape) or use text with the image as a background (use css to arrange the button).

Comment: That's a great explanation. Actually I have tried your css suggestion and result looks great.